# Getting distribution error in Devoops pipeline to Epicenter

Tags: appcenter

I just started getting 500 error.

I have a IOS pipeline that sends the info to Appcenter to distribute the app to test flight. Now getting error. No changes on my side.

##[error]{"code":"internal_server_error","message":"internal error (Support ID: c86b8112-a084-486c-9df8-a5ffc63fad81)"}
http response code: 500